determinant of cohomology of symplectic local systems
Let $X$ be an algebraic curve over $\mathbb C$ and let $E$ be a symplectic local system on $X$. For simplicity let us assume that $H^0(E)=H^2(E)=0$. Then $H^1(E)$ has a symmetric bilinear form and thus the square of its determinant is canonically trivialized.
$\mathbf{Question:}$ Is there a canonical trivialization of the determinant of $H^1(E)$ whose square is equal to the above trivialization of $\det(H^1(E))^{\otimes 2}$?

Take a cell decomposition of $X$ which gives a chain complex computing the cohomology of $E$. The alternating product of determinants of this chain complex is the same before and after you take cohomology, and is a power of $\det(E)$, so can be trivialized by the canonical trivialization of $\det(E)$. Maybe this one works?

Where exactly are you using the symplectic structure on E?

To trivialize the determinant of $E$.

I actually think that it is important that the form on E is skew-symmetric (but I might be wrong)
